# Method overiding and inheritance

Tags: php

The code below:

```
class A {
    public function foo() {}
}

class B extends A {
    private function foo() {}
}
```

gets me an error :"Access level to B::foo() must be public (as in class A)"

Why can't I override class A foo method in class B as private?

Comment: No, you cannot, it has to be either public or private.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear about that, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Rules of Access Specifiers in Method Overriding

The only rule says:

"The subclass overridden method cannot have weaker access than super class method".

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
    public function foo() {}
}

class B extends A {
    private function foo() {}
}
```

You can't override a public function with a private function, if you want to override the function both have to be public.